# parallel image processing artifacts

Tags: c#, image, parallel-processing, emgucv

I capture images from a webcam, do some heavy processing on them, and then show the result. To keep the framerate high, i want to have the processing of different frames run in parallel.

So, I have a 'Producer', which captures the images and adds these to the 'inQueue'; also it takes an image from the 'outQueue' and displays it:

```
public class Producer
{
    Capture capture;
    Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> inQueue;
    Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> outQueue;
    Object lockObject;
    Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox screen;
    public int frameCounter = 0;

    public Producer(Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox screen, Capture capture, Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> inQueue, Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> outQueue, Object lockObject)
    {
        this.screen = screen;
        this.capture = capture;
        this.inQueue = inQueue;
        this.outQueue = outQueue;
        this.lockObject = lockObject;
    }

    public void produce()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                inQueue.Enqueue(capture.QueryFrame());

                if (inQueue.Count == 1)
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(lockObject);
                }
                if (outQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    screen.Image = outQueue.Dequeue();                      
                }
            }
            frameCounter++;
        }           
    }
}
```

There are different 'Consumers' who take an image from the inQueue, do some processing, and add them to the outQueue:

```
public class Consumer
{
    Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> inQueue;
    Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> outQueue;
    Object lockObject;
    string name;

    Image<Bgr, Byte> image;

    public Consumer(Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> inQueue, Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> outQueue, Object lockObject, string name)
    {
        this.inQueue = inQueue;
        this.outQueue = outQueue;
        this.lockObject = lockObject;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void consume()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (inQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(lockObject);
                    continue;
                }                
                image = inQueue.Dequeue();   
            }

            // Do some heavy processing with the image

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                outQueue.Enqueue(image);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Rest of the important code is this section:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Consumer[] c = new Consumer[consumerCount];
        Thread[] t = new Thread[consumerCount];

        Object lockObj = new object();
        Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> inQueue = new Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>>();
        Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>> outQueue = new Queue<Image<Bgr, Byte>>();

        p = new Producer(screen1, capture, inQueue, outQueue, lockObj);

        for (int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++)
        {
            c[i] = new Consumer(inQueue, outQueue, lockObj, "c_" + Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new Thread(c[i].consume);
            t[i].Start();
        }

        Thread pt = new Thread(p.produce);
        pt.Start();
    }
```

The parallelisation actually works fine, I do get a linear speed increase with each added thread (up to a certain point of course). The problem is that I get artifacts in the output, even if running only one thread. The artifacts look like part of the picture is not in the right place.

[Example of the artifact (this is without any processing to keep it clear, but the effect is the same)](http://i47.tinypic.com/rm1udf.jpg)

Any ideas what causes this?
Thanks

Comment: That´s the stuff how old games were made. Basically, you are trying to mix up old technique concepts with new one´s. And that´s the reason why it does not really work. You need to use multiple Threads (what you already do). I am not really a game developer, but I think you should not use the EventQue or any Monitor lock. You are able to simply overdraw images without getting deadlocks. But I am not sure about it. So, I didnt post anything, cause am not exactly know the solution. But I think you should think about my solution suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Displaimer: This post isn't supposed to fully describe an answer, but instead give some hints on why the artifact is being shown.

A quick analysis show that the the actifact is, in fact, a partial, vertically mirrored snippet of a frame. I copied it, mirrored, and placed it back over the image, and added an awful marker to show its placement:

[image]

Two things immediately come to attention:

- The artifact is roughly positioned on the 'correct' place it would be, only that the position is also vertically mirrored;
- The image is slightly different, indicating that it may belong to a different frame.

It's been a while since I played around with raw capture and ran into a similar issue, but I remember that depending on how the driver is implemented (or set up - this particular issue happened when setting a specific imaging device for interlaced capture) it may fill its framebuffer alternating between 'top-down' and 'bottom-up' scans - as soon as the frame is full, the 'cursor' reverts direction.

It seems to me that you're running into a race condition/buffer underrun situation, where the transfer from the framebuffer to your application is happening before the full frame is transferred by the device.

In that case, you'd receive a partial image, and the area still not refreshed would show a bit of the previously transferred frame.

If I'd have to bet, I'd say that the artifact may appear on sequential order, not on the same position but 'fluctuating' on a specific direction (up or down), but always as a mirrored bit.

Comment: Maybe it's because under load the Producer thread can get preempted while it tries to capture?  I would try writing the raw captures to disk before processing to investigate.

Comment: That's a possibility, @bmm6o, you're correct - but again, it depends heavily on implementation.

Comment: Though if that's the case it's a bug in `Producer.QueryFrame()`.  Is that your code or 3rd party?

Comment: Producer.QueryFrame() may as well be the last victim in a cascading error chain, @bmm6o. My bet would be on the framebuffer semaphore, the part that tells the consumer application that a frame is available to be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the problem is here . The section of code is not guarantee that you will be access by one thread in here between two queue. The image is pop by **inQueue** is not actually received in order in **outQueue**

```
while (true)
{
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (inQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(lockObject);
                continue;
            }                
            image = inQueue.Dequeue();   
        }

        // Do some heavy processing with the image

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            outQueue.Enqueue(image);
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you test your fix?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @OnoSendai, I'm not trying to solve the exact problem as stated. I would have to write an app and I just don't have the time. But, the two things that I would change right away would be to use the `ConcurrentQueue` class so that you have thread-safety. And, I would use the Task library functions in order to create parallel tasks on different processor cores. These are found in the System.Net and System.Net.Task namespaces.

Also, vertically flipping a chunk like that looks like more than an artifact to me. If it also happens when executing in a single thread as you mentioned, then I would definitely re-focus on the "heavy processing" part of the equation.

Good luck! Take care.

Answer (score 0):

You may have two problems:

1) parallism doesn't ensure that images are added to the out queue in the right order. I imagine that displaying image 8 before image 6 and 7 can produce some artifacts. In consumer thread, you have to wait previous consumer have posted its image to the out queue to post next image. Tasks can help greatly for that because of their inherent synchronisation mecanism.

2) You may also have problems in the rendering code.